# MongoDB: aggregate error when use Match and Group

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I've model

```
var LogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userId: String,
    pageId: String,
    tagId: String
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

In code,

```
 Log.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                createdAt: {
                    $gte: new Date(strFrom),             
                    $lte: new Date(strTo),             
                }
            },            
            //$group: { _id: "$userId" },            
        }
    ], function (err, logs) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({ message: "error retrieving logs." });
        } else {
            res.send(logs);
        }
    });
```

When I execute code use $match, that's ok. Then, I add $group, I receive error

Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

So, I remove $match, only use $grooup, code run ok. So, when I use both $match and $group, receive errors.

Please, give me ideas

Thank so much

Comment: `$group` has to be outside of the `$match` stage

Comment: Why don't you just use [**distinct**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#distinct_distinct) `Log.distinct('userId', { createdAt: {
                    $gte: new Date(strFrom),             
                    $lte: new Date(strTo),             
                } }, function (err, logs) { ... });`?

Comment: Because I want to filter data by date, distinct userId and paging. So distinct method not support paging, so I must use aggregate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing brace.

```
Log.aggregate([{
     $match: {
         createdAt: {
             $gte: new Date(strFrom),             
             $lte: new Date(strTo),             
         }
     }, 
     {  <-- missing brace around your group           
        $group: { _id: "$userId" },            
     }], 
     function (err, logs) {
        if (err) {
           res.status(500).send({ message: "error retrieving logs." });
        } else {
           res.send(logs);
     }
});
```